How to navigate to root Bottom Navigation Menu Item on Android
I'm developing a Android app with Navigation Component with Fragments and a NavGraph.
My app has a BottomNavigationView with Menu Items like described in "Tie destinations to menu items"
From my HomeFragment I can navigate to a DetailFragment by selecting some element from a list.
However, when I select another item (e.g. SecondFragment) from the Bottom Nav and then select the HomeFragment item, I end up in the DetailView again.
The intended Behaviour is to navigate to the (parent) HomeFragment. How do I do that?
I'm using androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment and androidx.navigation:navigation-ui 2.7.7.

My Code looks like:
// MainActivity
NavHostFragment navHostFragment = (NavHostFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.nav_host_fragment);
    
NavController navController = navHostFragment.getNavController();
    
bottomNavigationView = findViewById(R.id.bottom_navigation);
NavigationUI.setupWithNavController(bottomNavigationView, navController);

<!-- bottom_nav_menu.xml -->
<item
    android:id="@+id/homeFragment"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_home_black_24dp"
    android:title="@string/label_program" />
<item
    android:id="@+id/secondFragment"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_star_black_24dp"
    android:title="@string/label_second" />
...

<!-- activity_main.xml -->
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    ...

    <androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView
        android:id="@+id/nav_host_fragment"
        android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        app:defaultNavHost="true"
        app:navGraph="@navigation/nav_graph" />

    <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/bottom_navigation"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:background="@color/colorWhite"
        app:menu="@menu/bottom_nav_menu" />

</LinearLayout>

Inside my HomeFragments onItemClick I navigate by:
bundle.putInt(ItemDetailFragment.ARG_PARAM1, mItems.get(position).item.getId());
navController.navigate(R.id.itemDetailFragment, bundle);

Thanks in advance!

I ended up implementing a NavigationBarView.OnItemSelectedListener. First I added a global Actions to my NavGraph for the HomeFragment and the SecondFragment, when modified the MainActivity.
In my MainActivity:
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    NavHostFragment navHostFragment = (NavHostFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
        .findFragmentById(R.id.nav_host_fragment);

    navController = navHostFragment.getNavController();
    bottomNavigationView = findViewById(R.id.bottom_navigation);
    NavigationUI.setupWithNavController(bottomNavigationView, navController);
    bottomNavigationView.setOnItemSelectedListener(navListener); // set a own Listener
}

private final NavigationBarView.OnItemSelectedListener navListener = new NavigationBarView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem menuItem) {
        int itemId = menuItem.getItemId();
        if (R.id.homeFragment == itemId) {
            navController.navigate(HomeFragmentDirections.actionGlobalHomeFragment());
        } else if (R.id.favoritesFragment == itemId) {
            navController.navigate(HomeFragmentDirections.actionGlobalSecondFragment());
        }

        return true;
    }
};

